# how to achieve a sliding effect to show the rest of elements in a grid, with views

Tags: views, paging, javascript

I have a view set to grid, displaying 5 items per column. I set it to display 5 items at a time too, but I have 10 items total. What i want to achieve is, when I click on page 2, instead of having it load the rest of thumbs, for them to slide into the position of the first 5 items displayed. It would be something like SlideShow effect, scroll to the left, but instead of displaying a single frame, displaying 5 at a time.

Im using drupal 6x, views, (cck of course), and have slideshow installed but I couldn't manage to figure it our on my own. I appreciate any prompt response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example of jquery slide show.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>jQuery Animating an Element</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#right").click(function() {
                $("#theDiv").animate({ width: "500px" }, 1000);
            });
            $("#text").click(function() {
                $("#theDiv").animate({ fontSize: "24pt" }, 1000);
            });
            $("#toggle").click(function() {
                $("#theDiv").animate({ left: "500" }, 1000, "swing");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        div#theDiv {
            position:relative;
            width: 250px;
            height: 180px;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 20px;
            background: cyan;
            border: 2px solid black;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        p, span {
            font-size: 16pt;
        }
        button {
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Animating an Element</p>
    <div id="theDiv">Animate Me</div>
    <button id="right">Grow Right</button>
    <button id="text">Big Text</button>
    <button id="toggle">Move Div</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you need more info then tell me.

Comment: Hello Rishi, thank you very much for your response. Do you know if this may conflict with Views Slideshow I have already installed for other functionalities? I have the jquery module and the jquery libraries for date already installed, but wondered if you knew of a reported conflict. I really appreciate your response. :)

Comment: Also, for what I see this would basically apply to the thumbs container, right? So if my container is "div#thumb-views-block-1", this would be what gets scrolled, am I correct?